# Modifying Constraints

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

As an exercise for learning Swift and iOS development I decided to make the [Breakout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breakout_%28video_game%29) game. Right at the start I encountered a simple problem, that I can't find a simple solution for.

I started with the paddle. I created a `gameView` which will be the container for the game. I also created the `paddleView` and added constraints that will put the paddle in the right position. Here's what I have:

[image]

I also added a pan gesture recognizer that positions the paddle's `center.x` position.

Here's the problem: when I change orientation, the paddle moves to center regardless of the position prior to the change.

[image]
[image]

I tried creating an outlet of the `Center X Alignment Constraint`, removing it in `viewWillTransitionToSize`, and restoring previous position in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` but paddle's `origin.x` was always 0. I also tried modifying the constraint, maybe changing the `multiplier`, but still unsuccessful.

I know there's a simple solution to this, but I can't find it.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not modify view center.x in your pan gesture handler because your constrains will be break. Instead you should create constraint outlet (let say for constraint : view.center.x equal superview.center.x) and change its constant value in your pan handler.

```
@IBOutlet weak var centerAlignment: NSLayoutConstraint!

@IBAction func handleDrag(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    let xPosition = sender.locationInView(self.view).x

    if  xPosition >= 0 && xPosition <= self.view.frame.size.width{

        centerAlignment.constant = xPosition - self.view.frame.size.width / 2

    } else if xPosition > self.view.frame.size.width {

        centerAlignment.constant = self.view.frame.size.width / 2

    } else {

        centerAlignment.constant = -self.view.frame.size.width / 2
    }

}
```