# Change the size of an UIButton on screen size of iPhone

Tags: iphone, swift, uibutton, autolayout

I want to change the size(width, height) of the UIButton where auto layout feature is on. Following is the code which works properly which auto layout feature is off. What changes i should do to make the code work when auto layout feature is on.

```
    println("height :  \(height)")
    println("width :  \(width)")
    if (height == 460)
    {
        btn1.frame = CGRectMake(22, 66, 40, 40)
        //btn1.sizeToFit()

        //btn1.frame = CGRectMake(200, 200, 100, 100)
        println("480")
        self.view.addSubview(btn1)
    }
    else if (height == 548)
    {
       btn1.frame = CGRectMake(22, 66, 60, 60)


        //btn1.frame.size.height = 65;
        //CGRect frame = btn1.frame;
        //btn1.frame.size.height = btn1.frame.size.height-20;
        //btn1.frame = CGRectMake(200, 200, 100, 100)
        println("548")
        //btn1.sizeToFit()
        //self.view.addSubview(btn1)
    }
    else
    {
        //btn1.sizeToFit()
        btn1.frame = CGRectMake(22, 66, 75, 75)
        //btn1.frame = CGRectMake(200, 200, 100, 100)
        println("647")
        self.view.addSubview(btn1)
    }
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30300015/modifying-constraints/30301168#30301168

Answer (score 0):

You need to add constraints programmatically.

```
// After initialize button
btn1.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
self.view.addSubView(btn1)

// Left
self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: btn1, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 22))

// Top
self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: btn1, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 66))

// Width
btn1.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: btn1, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 60))

// Height
btn1.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: btn1, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 60))
```