# layoutIfNeeded doesn't take effect when a view has subview(s)

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

Under Auto Layout, I change a view's position by setting its `center.x`, then I call `layoutIfNeeded`. What I expect is the view will go back to its previous position, it does without any subview, but doesn't with at least one subview.

I make a simple demo to show the question:

```
@IBAction func move(sender: AnyObject) {
    singleView.center.x += 20
    viewWithSubview.center.x += 20
}

@IBAction func back(sender: AnyObject) {
    singleView.layoutIfNeeded()
    viewWithSubview.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

The original scene:

[image]

After `move` is called:

[image]

After `back` is called:

[image]

I know `setNeedsLayout` can make the second view back, but that's not the answer I want. I want to know why it happens as I described above.

Comment: If you're using Auto Layout you should be changing `constant` on your `NSLayoutConstraint`s to change the positions of your views.

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/a/30301168/1422333

Comment: Thanks, I know what you means, but my aim isn't to change the position of these views, I just want to know why it happens as I described, especially for the difference between with and without subview(s)